# Remove Wordpress Kentha Theme Purchase Code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, activation

I bought the Kentha Theme ver 3.2.2 and when I installed it on Wordpress, it was asking for an activation code. I had got the theme a long time ago and have forgot my credentials on Envato Market, so I can't really access the purchase code. How do I bypass the purchase code pop-up and gain access to the full theme since I want to use it for my website. Any help would be grateful!

P.S. I tried resetting my password... no luck sadly, must have used one of my spam emails.

Comment: Check your email and reset it otherwise no one can do this

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Try contacting the vendor from which you purchased said product to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact Envato support, bypassing the license system is illegal and risky at the same time.
Look into your downloaded theme folder, there should be a text document containing your purchase information.

Answer (score 0):

Simply contact Envato, give them your transaction ID, and then they will get it to sort it for you.